# page not redirecting after session expires

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

i have done a simple page to move to another page when session expires. I have set the time as 50 seconds and after that it will move to a page But unfortunately its not moving and i am helpless to know where is the wrong. I would be very much grateful if you please solve my problem

```
function x(){
       var timeOut =<%=session.getAttribute("login")%>;

var checkTimeout;

checkTimeOut = function(){
    if(timeOut==null || timeOut==""){
        window.location.replace("failedSession.jsp");
//document.getElementById("b").innerHTML="session timed out";
        // redirect to timeout page
    }else{


        window.setTimeout(checkTimeOut, 1000); // check once per second
    }}
checkTimeOut(); // this is where you insert checkTimeOut function so that when you call x(), this will execute in the end.
}
```

Comment: You will find your code easier to read if you put a semicolon at the end of this line of JavaScript so it matches the others:  var timeOut = <%=session.getMaxInactiveInterval() %>;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem with your code:**

Nowhere in your code, you are calling `checkTimeOut();`. Which is why it is not being executed. You should have checked the execution of the function by putting `alert` inside the function. Probably do it during `body onload` as `@rgeorge` has suggested.

**Note:** Your logic looks alright. Also have habit of putting semicolons after `javascript` *statements* as `@Mark` has suggested.

**Answer Updated:**

**1)** Don't use `function name` and `variable` name same. For ex: `x`. Have names unique. It is conflicting.

**2)** Your `x` is always greater than `lastActivity + timeOut` because `x` is not increasing (7 > 1+1). Which means `else` condition will never execute. Which means `checkTimeOut` will never be called.

**3)** Your function `checkTimeOut()` itself will never execute because it is never called from anywhere. You are only executing `x()`. This is not sufficient to call `checkTimeOut()`.

**Answer Updated:**

**Do as this:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function x(){
       var timeOut =1;
var lastActivity = 1;
var x=7;

var checkTimeout;

checkTimeOut = function(){
    if(x > lastActivity + timeOut){
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML=x;
        // redirect to timeout page
    }else{
        window.setTimeout(checkTimeOut, 1000); // check once per second
    }}
checkTimeOut(); // this is where you insert checkTimeOut function so that when you call x(), this will execute in the end.
}

    </script>
```

**Your** code works fine for me. The `DIV` value changes to `7`. And that is what your code does >> http://jsfiddle.net/hmHP9/

Comment: thanks for replying,i have been trying it in another way and hence forgot to post the originla code. well i have edited my post and even still it is not working

Comment: i am manullay giving the values and checking but its not dsiplaying x

Comment: yes else conditon will never execute so the document.getElementById("b").innerHTML=x; in if condition will execute and it will print the value of x but its not printing

Comment: My friend, your function `checkTimeOut()` itself will never execute because it is never called from anywhere. You are only executing `x()`. This is not sufficient to call `checkTimeOut()`.

Comment: see i tried this but this is also not working <script type="text/javascript">
function x(){
       var timeOut =5;
var lastActivity = 1;
var x=4;

var checkTimeout;

checkTimeOut = function(){
    if(x > lastActivity + timeOut){
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML=x;
        // redirect to timeout page
    }else{ lastActivity=lastActivity+1;document.getElementById("b").innerHTML=x;
        window.setTimeout(checkTimeOut, 1000); // check once per second
    }}
}
    </script>

Comment: check updated answer. see last line where I am calling `checkTimeOut()`.

Comment: its still not printing anything even if i change the value

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. The DIV value changes to 7. And that is what your code does >> http://jsfiddle.net/hmHP9/

Comment: @ra  thanks for your help. i have tested and it works perfectly but i got stuck when i modified a little 
instead of timeout=100*60 i made timout=<%session.getAttribute("login");%> to check if session is there or not but here its not working.please see my edited post

Comment: first i am checking is session available or not.if available then do else part or do if part. so after running its not working anything

Comment: Check this out >> http://jsfiddle.net/LgRtx/. Also replace `timeOut = null` and run. Is this what you want ? Looks alright to me.

Comment: see my idea is to get the session attribute in and check if session is there or not. if the session is not there go to login page. I wanted to implement this idea with your code. so in the timeout variable i am getting the session.getAttribute("login"). when the session is invalidated then session.getAttribute("login") will return null. so as per my code it will go to if part and hence it will go back to login page. I hope you understand my idea

Comment: Yes, I understand. So, what's the exact problem ? What part of the code is trouble ?

Comment: see you are doing the hard code value in timeOut value, i just want to give dynamically which depends on the session inactive interval. for one time if session interval is 20 then timeOut will be 20 and if session inactive interval is 100 then timeout wil be 100

Comment: Hard coded value is for test. I can't test with your session attribute. You need to `system.out` the session value to see what's in there.

Comment: that is only my problem when i use var timeOut=<%=session.getAttribute("sessionName")%> then its not working. Please tell me this is the right way or not

Comment: i did as you said but till now i am not getting why . I have edited the question as well.please have a look

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your comment. Please rephrase it.

Comment: see i have done the way you said and also i have posted the question but till now my problem is not solved

Comment: what are you using ? `<%=session.getAttribute("login")%>;` or `<%=session.getAttribute("sessionName")%>` ? what is the value of this ?

Comment: session.getAttribute("login") gives the login name. if you login with ABC then session.getAtrribute("login") gives you ABC

Comment: well then this is wrong. you don't assign string to number timeout. This is completely wrong. Don't you know that ?

Comment: well i am not assigning string to number. timeOut is just a variable where i am storing the session object and in the if part i am checking if session object is null or not

Comment: Oops, sorry, my mistake. You should not store session object in JS variable. Do like this. Store some string attribute in session. And then retrieve it in JS variable. that should do.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30550/discussion-between-javal-and-ravi-trivedi)

Answer (score 0):

The code you have pasted does not seem to be invoking the checktimeout function initially.  This applies to your revised code as well.  It is only defining the function checktimeout().

I would add an onload function call to the body tag which invokes the checktime out the first time.

```
function startTimeoutCheck() {
    window.setTimeout(checkTimeout, 1000);
}

<body onload="startTimeoutCheck()">
    ....
</body>
```

The checktimout variable should obviously be in the scope (global) of the above function.

Comment: thanks for answering and i have edited my post and even still it is not working